# Can I use “bon” or “bien” when saying “It's good to be here?”

Tags: usage, expressions-idiomatiques, adjectifs, adverbes

How do I say “It's good to be here?”  Is it “*C'est bon*” or “*C'est bien*” *d'être ici*?

Comment: "On est bien, ici." , "Ca me fait plaisir d'être ici.", "Je suis bien, ici."

Answer (score 9):

I would say “*je suis content d'être ici*” to mean “I'm happy to be here” or “I'm glad to be here”. In more formal contexts, the correct adjective would be *heureux*: “je suis heureux d'être parmi vous ce soir” (“I am happy to be with you tonight”).

Another possibility is “*ça fait du bien d'être ici*”. This means literally “being here makes me/one feel good”.

“*C'est bon d'être ici*” means about the same thing but is a bit more informal and less idiomatic.

“*C'est bien d'être ici*” is also less idiomatic, unless what you want to convey is that it's a good thing to be here, as in the opposite of an evil thing.

Answer (score 5):

Not given in the other answers:

> (1) Qu'on est bien ici !
>
> (2) Que c'est bon d'être ici !
>
> (3) Que c'est bien d'être ici !

(1) and (2) give a general happiness sensation. (3) will be used with a specific reason in mind which will often be given after (*Que c'est bien d'être ici plutôt que là où le soleil tape*).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to say

- If you want to say that being here makes you feel good, it's *bon* for you to be here
- If you want to say that being here is a generally good or right thing, it's *bien* to be here

so generally speaking *bon* appeals to emotion and feelings, and *bien* refers to intellect or moral.